# Inconsistent breakpoint exceptions during debugger attachment on freshly created process (Windows)

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi

While creating a suspended process and attaching a debugger to it, sometimes 2 breakpoint exceptions are captured in the debug loop, and sometimes only 1.

Code example (in this case I'm using notepad.exe as a debug target but it can be anything):

```
    STARTUPINFO sinfo = { 0 };
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo = { 0 };

    DWORD flags = 0;
    flags |= CREATE_SUSPENDED;

    CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"), 0, 0, 0, FALSE, flags, 0, 0, &sinfo, &pinfo);

    DebugActiveProcess(pinfo.dwProcessId);
    DEBUG_EVENT dbg;
    ResumeThread(pinfo.hThread);

    while (true)
    {
        if (WaitForDebugEvent(&dbg, 100))
        {
            switch (dbg.dwDebugEventCode) {

            case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
                printf("exception: 0x%p [%p] (tid: %d)\n", dbg.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress, dbg.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode, dbg.dwThreadId);
                break;
            }

            ContinueDebugEvent(dbg.dwProcessId, dbg.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
        }
    }
```

After running this code a few times, sometimes the output is:

```
exception: 0x00007FF9E1FE0950 [0000000080000003] (tid: ...)
exception: 0x00007FF9E1FB0BB0 [0000000080000003] (tid: ...)
```

And sometimes:

```
exception: 0x00007FF9E1FE0950 [0000000080000003] (tid: ...)
```

The exception at 0x00007FF9E1FE0950 is inside ntdll.dll:LdrpDoDebuggerBreak.

The exception at 0x00007FF9E1FB0BB0 is inside ntdll.dll:DbgBreakPoint.

Hence, sometimes the DbgBreakPoint breakpoint exception does not occur.
From the randomness of this, I assume there's some kind of a race condition there.

I do know about DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS flag in CreateProcess, but I would like to know if this is a known issue (I haven't found any info about it) or an expected behavior and that debugging processes that hasn't started yet should always be done with DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS (or DEBUG_PROCESS) in CreateProcess function.

I expected a consistent behavior of 2 exceptions or only 1 exception.

Comment: Your code has *undefined behavior* as your call to `printf()` is using `%p` to print a `DWORD` instead of a pointer (and `%d` to print a `DWORD` instead of an `int`). It is clear from the output that you are building for 64bit, where `%p` expects an 8-byte pointer, not a 4-byte integer. Fix the placeholders you are using.

Comment: And, since you are wanting to debug the process right away you are launching, you really should specify the `DEBUG_PROCESS` and `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` flags in the `CreateProcess()` call. Get rid of `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, `DebugActiveProcess()`, and `ResumeThread()`, you don't need them.

Comment: On a side note, exception `0x80000003` is `EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT`. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970645/65863), which describes a caveat with handling `EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT` events that your code is not accounting for yet.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of the %p issue, this is just isn't important at the moment because I just wanted an easy print of value in hex and was lazy to google for the hex version of %d :)

Comment: And yes, I am aware of the DEBUG_PROCESS and DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, My question is the behavior I've experienced is normal.

Comment: Did you verify that [`WaitForDebugEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugevent) reports a timeout by returning zero? The documentation doesn't seem to cover this.